# Is it allowed to use background-image behind adsense

Tags: html, css, adsense

Is it allowed to use "background-image" behind advertising for display a message for visitors who use adblock:

```
div.adsense{
height: 90px;
width 720px;
background: url(../promo.png) no-repeat;
}

<div class="adsense">
<script> ads </script>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Use In Css**

```
background-image: url("Here Your Img Url");
```

**For Example**

```
div.adsense{
height: 90px;
width 720px;
background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/36487/above-adventure-aerial-air.jpg");
color:#FFF;
}
```

[Demo in Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/t7otsk12/2/)

Comment: But is it allowed?